# Хук на чтение файла

Tags: c#, hook, файлы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как узнать, что другое приложение обратилось к какому либо файлу?

Comment: Может быть, вам подойдёт просто [`procmon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)? Там и фильтры есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На СodeProject есть неплохой проект по этому поводу: [EasyHook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking). Поддерживает создание различных хуков, в том числе и для функций работы с файлами.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно подойдет [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)?

Comment: на чтение ничего там нету 

"события при изменениях каталога или файла в каталоге"